# jQuery Isotope filtering: add a class when there are no items in a data-category in the grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope layout with sorting of grid items by a filter; and when items are sorted by button, the items in the grid that are not in the selected data-category have their CSS opacity changed to .25.

The problem is that when the grid is complete - either on initial page load or after an "arrangeComplete" by the button action of sorting - there are certain data-categories that have no items in the grid. This means that some sorting buttons are still clickable even though they don't sort because they have no items in the grid.

I want to add a class to these buttons, and also "declick" the button(s) so that they are not active links.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WooJom

I.e.: the buttons All, Red, Green, Blue, White all have items and sort; buttons Orange and Gray have no items, so I want to add a class to them and "declick" them.

How can I

> 1) count the items in the grid,
>
> 2) find if there are zero items, and if so
>
> 3) add a class to the button(s) so that the buttons have an opacity of
>   .25, and
>
> 4) the button(s) are also declicked so they are not an active link?

*Where and how do I add to this function to do that?*

```
var selectedCategory;

var $grid = $('.isotope-list').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 160,
    gutter: 20
  },
  getSortData: {
    selectedCategory: function( itemElem ) {
      return $( itemElem ).hasClass( selectedCategory ) ? 0 : 1;
    }
  }
});


var $items = $('.row').find('.grid-item');

$('.sort-button-group').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
  // set selectedCategory
  selectedCategory = $( this ).attr('data-category');
  if ( selectedCategory == 'all' ) {
    $grid.isotope({
      sortBy: 'original-order'
    });

    // restore all items to full opacity
    $items.css({
      opacity: 1
    });
    return;
  }


  // change opacity for selected/unselected items
  var selectedClass = '.' + selectedCategory;
  $items.filter( selectedClass ).css({
    opacity: 1
  });
  $items.not( selectedClass ).css({
    opacity: 0.25
  });

  // update sort data now that selectedCategory has changed
  $grid.isotope('updateSortData');
  $grid.isotope({ sortBy: 'selectedCategory' });
});

  // change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

HTML for the buttons; I need to add a class to these buttons:

```
<div class="button-container">
<div class="button-group sort-button-group">
<button class="button is-checked" data-category="all">all</button>
<button class="button" data-category="red">red</button>
<button class="button" data-category="green">green</button>
<button class="button" data-category="blue">blue</button>
<button class="button" data-category="white">white</button>
<button class="button" data-category="orange">orange</button>
<button class="button" data-category="gray">gray</button>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achived by the binding a callback on [`arrangeComplete`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html#arrangecomplete) event. It trigger this on page `load`, you will need to set [`initLayout`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#initlayout) to `false` in the isotope's setup options and run the following to manually trigger initial layout:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  ...
  // disable initial layout
  initLayout: false,
  ...
});

// ********** Event binding **********
// use $grid.one('arrangeComplete', ...) if it is only needed at initial page load
$grid.on('arrangeComplete', disableEmptySortButtons);

// manually trigger initial layout
$grid.isotope();
```

To get count of each category item, you can iterate over the sort button's categories, find the no of `grid-items` related to that category and if it happens to be `0`, perform the following for that sort button:

a) add a class `disable` for `opacity: 0.25` for the button appearance

b) set the `disabled` attribute to disable button's click functionality

Here's that function will look like:

```
var disableEmptySortButtons = function() {
  $('.button-group button').each(function(i, btn) {
    var $btn = $(btn),
        thisCategory = $btn.attr('data-category');
    if (thisCategory !== 'all' && $('.isotope-container').find('.' + thisCategory).length === 0) {
      $btn.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
};
```

Here's an updated [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVMJxj) for a complete working example.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly and your code makes sense to me, though I am a beginner with Isotope.