# Using jQuery to disable empty categories in a filtered listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am fairly new to Javascript/jQuery. I have a list of items (in this case, course offerings) structured in a UL. Each "course" is an LI element. The list is being filtered by categories using jQuery, which is controlling the visibility of each list item after checking its "data-category" attribute matches the selected category (a checkbox selected by the user).

This is all working great.

I have a further requirement that users should not see "0 results" when selecting a combination of filters/categories. So, I have to check each category will not return an empty set. If it will, I wish to disable that category.

To start, I followed this example: [jQuery Isotope filtering: add a class when there are no items in a data-category in the grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666226/jquery-isotope-filtering-add-a-class-when-there-are-no-items-in-a-data-category)

This is the code I came up with:

```
        // whenever a category is selected, check all categories to see which ones
        // would be empty if selected.
        // To do this, we iterate over all categories, then over all visible items, and check if their data-category contains
        // the category that matches the current category. If 0 items match, disable that category.
        function DisableEmptyCategories() {
            $allCategories = $(".checkboxlist input[type='checkbox']");
            $allCategories.each(function (i, element) {
                var $checkbox = $(element);
                // check if checkbox's value is in any displayed item's data-category tag.
                var val = $checkbox.val();
                if (val !== undefined) {
                    if ($filteredResults.find('[data-category~="' + val + '"]').length == 0) {
                        // if equals 0, disable. 
                        $checkbox.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                    else {
                        // else, make sure it's enabled.
                        $checkbox.removeClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'false');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Unfortunately, the end result is that it disables all of my categories every time, and I cannot figure out why. I have checked that the $filteredResults list is populated correctly as is the val variable. However it seems my .find() isn't working and always returns 0.

Here is a fiddle illustrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/yvgx81k4/
In this example, there are items matching all categories except "In-Class", so only the "In-Class" category should be disabled, but all of them get disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `prop('disabled', true)` and `prop('disabled', false)`, not `attr`, with Boolean attributes like "disabled". `attr('disabled', 'false')` causes the checkbox to remain disabled because the checkbox is disabled based on the presence or absence of the "disabled" attribute, not its value.

Comment: Oh, thanks @HereticMonkey, I didn't know that. I have updated that locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not selecting the correct `li` is because of the selector you are using in your `find`, as you suspected.

In you code, you are doing this:

```
if ($('#courselist > li').find('[data-category~="' + val + '"]').length == 0) {
```

This is selecting all the `li`s and then looking for *their* children that have the matching data-category... but the data-category is an attribute of the `li`, not it's child.

Instead, you can select `courselist` and then look for its children that have the correct data-category, i.e.

```
if ($('#courselist').find('[data-category~="' + val + '"]').length == 0) {
```

Here it is in a working snippet, based on your fiddle:
*(I've also used* `prop` *as HereticMonkey suggested, but this isn't the reason your selector was failing)*

```js
$('.checkboxlist input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

$allCategories = $(".checkboxlist input[type='checkbox']");
  $allCategories.each(function(i, element) {
    var $checkbox = $(element);
    // check if checkbox's value is in any displayed item's data-category tag.
    var val = $checkbox.val();
    if (val !== undefined) {
      console.log(val);
      if ($('#courselist').find('[data-category~="' + val + '"]').length == 0) {
        // if equals 0, disable.
        $checkbox.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        // else, make sure it's enabled.
        $checkbox.removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#menu,
#content {
  float: left;
}

/* disabled checkbox */

.checkboxlist input[type='checkbox'].disabled+label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="menu">
    <p>
      Delivery
    </p>
    <ul id="chkDelivery" class="list-unstyled checkboxlist">
      <li><input id="Delivery_0" type="checkbox" name="Delivery" value="Online" />
        <label for="Delivery_0">Online</label>
      </li>
      <li><input id="Delivery_1" type="checkbox" name="Delivery" value="InClass" />
        <label for="Delivery_1">In-Class</label></li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      Fees
    </p>
    <ul id="chkFees" class="list-unstyled checkboxlist">
      <li>
        <input id="Fees_0" type="checkbox" name="Fees" value="Free" />
        <label for="Fees_0">Free</label></li>
      <li>
        <input id="Fees_1" type="checkbox" name="Fees" value="Paid" />
        <label for="Fees_1">Paid</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>
      Course List
    </h2>
    <ul id="courselist" class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="course" data-category="Free Online">Free Online Course Title - CRSE-1000</li>
      <li class="course" data-category="Paid Online">Paid Online Course Title - CRSE-1000</li>
      <li class="course" data-category="Paid Online">Paid Online Course Title - CRSE-1000</li>
      <li class="course" data-category="Free Online">Free Online Course Title - CRSE-1000</li>
      <li class="course" data-category="Paid Online">Paid Online Course Title - CRSE-1000</li>
      <li class="course" data-category="Free Online">Free Online Course Title - CRSE-1000</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `prop('disabled', false)`, not `prop('disabled', 'false')`, as non-empty strings are truthy... Probably should just use `prop('disabled', true)` just to make it clear.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, I'll make that change, I mis-typed when I was transcribing it from your comment Had spotted the `true`but not the `'` (Should probably have rechecked it :) )

Comment: @FluffyKitten Well, that explains it. Thank you! That definitely was confusing for me. But since in my actual application I am passing in a variable, which contains only the "visible" i.e. filtered list items (LI elements) - is there something I can use in place of "find()" that will search within the elements themselves? I think if I were to pass in the whole UL list, it would find all the categories, including ones on elements that are not selected/visible.

Comment: @user0474975 I'm sure there is but we'd need to see what that variable contains first before being able to help with that :) It sounds like a different problem though, so it could change the question & answer which isn't how Stack Over flow works. Questions here are meant to help other users too, so the guidelines are to keep each one focused on a single problem. Can you show me a short example of what the variable contains, and if it is still in the context of this question I'll edit my answer; If it's not then it is perfectly acceptable to ask it as a separate question!

Comment: @FluffyKitten It's an (array?) of LI elements, which is a subset of the original UL list items. I just found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756777/jquery-find-element-by-data-attribute-value (the second answer) - use filter() instead of find(). I used it as a direct replacement in my code and it's working perfectly now. Your answer was correct about the use of find() and led me to be able to fix my problem, so I'm accepting.

Comment: @user0474975 Thanks, glad you got it sorted! Yeah, `filter` can be a great little function.